# Agregar clase active en menu Bootstrap con JQuery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Tengo este menu

```html
<ul class="nav menu">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="admin.php">
      <svg class="glyph stroked dashboard-dial">
        <use xlink:href="#stroked-dashboard-dial"></use>
      </svg> Inicio</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" onclick="load_div('contenido','archivo.php')">
      <svg class="glyph stroked calendar">
        <use xlink:href="#stroked-calendar"></use>
      </svg> Registrar</a>
  </li>
  <li >
    <a href="#" onclick="load_div('contenido','archivo.php')">
      <svg class="glyph stroked line-graph">
        <use xlink:href="#stroked-line-graph"></use>
      </svg> Registrar</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Quiero que se agregue la clase `active` al elemento `<li>` cuando se seleccione el elemento `<a>` interno.

Comment: que quieres decir con que se active la clase? puedes explicarlo de otra forma?

Comment: que se agregue la clase active en la etiqueta `<li>` cuando seleccione un `<a>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo, he simplificado el HTML pero conserva la misma estructura.

Funciona así: Primero utiliza `$(".nav li")` para seleccionar los elementos de la lista dentro del menu `.nav`. Luego utiliza el evento [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) para saber cuando se hace click sobre cualquiera de los elementos. Finalmente, dentro del evento click, elimina la clase `active` de todos los elementos y establece la clase `active` en el elemento clickeado.

He modificado un poco tu petición, si seleccionara los `<a>`, solo funcionaria haciendo click sobre el texto del enlace, pero no sobre las areas sin texto del `<li>` ni sobre el `<svg>`. Esto provoca, me parece, una mala experiencia de usuario, así que lo cambie para que abarque todo el `<li>`. Pero si quieres que solo funcione únicamente sobre el `<a>`, puedes cambiar el selector a: `".nav li a"`

```js
$(function() {
  
  // elementos de la lista
  var menues = $(".nav li"); 

  // manejador de click sobre todos los elementos
  menues.click(function() {
     // eliminamos active de todos los elementos
     menues.removeClass("active");
     // activamos el elemento clicado.
     $(this).addClass("active");
  });

});
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav menu">
  <li class="active">
    <a>Inicio</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Registrar</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Otra Opcion</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Este código lo utilizo en todos mis template, primero remuevo la clase  `active` de la opción que previamente estaba seleccionada y posteriormente la agrego a la opción que se selecciono.  Esto en la carga de la pantalla

```
$(function(){
    $("li").removeClass("active");
    $("#CargaMasiva").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: una consulta ese codigo que indicas exactamente en que parte de la estructura del esqueleto del archivo html se debe colocar..?

Comment: Generalmente es lanzada por un evento, ya sea un click, blur, etc. @JoseMHerreraV

Answer (score 2):

El ejemplo me funciona bien cuando lo hago en una página aparte, sería casi como lo ha hecho los demás colegas: Ejemplo:

```
<ul id="navi">
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">About MHG</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Workout Programs</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Fitness Tips</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Read Our Blog</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
$('a.menu').click(function(){
    $('a.menu').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

Aunque también pueden en vez de poner la clase menú dentro del vinculo `<a>`, ponerlo dentro del `<li>`, pero a mí en lo personal no me funciona cuando lo utilizo dentro de una plantilla que al hacer clic en el `<li>` me abre otra página manteniendo el mismo menú.

Comment: Hola @Luis. Bienvenido a [es.So] y gracias por tu aporte. Si a partir de esta publicación te genera el alguna otra pregunta, no la incluyas en la respuesta. En cambio, por favor publicala como una nueva pregunta