# ¿Porque no se agrega la clase active?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

tengo este menu

```
<section class="menu">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav" id="nav-menu">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="Nosotros.html">Nosotros</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicio al cliente</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </section>
```

cuando tengo la ruta "#" se agrega la clase active al item, pero cuando le coloco una ruta "nosotros.html" ya no se agrega la clase active

```
$(function() {
    var item = $(".nav-item");
    item.click(function() {
        item.removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

});
```

que podra ser?

Comment: Tal vez esto te sirva: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3642/agregar-clase-active-en-menu-bootstrap-con-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo que planteas deberías agregar `e.preventDefault()`. Por ejemplo:

```
$(function() {
    var item = $(".nav-item");
    item.click(function(e) {
        // Agregar:
        e.preventDefault();

        item.removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

});
```

Si vas a navegar entre páginas como si fueran pestañas lo siguiente no aplicaría:

```
$(function() {
    var item = $(".nav-item");
    item.click(function(e) {
        // Agregar:
        e.preventDefault();

        item.removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

});
```

En su lugar se debería colocar en:
**index.html**

```
<section class="menu">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav" id="nav-menu">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="Nosotros.html">Nosotros</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicio al cliente</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>
```

En **Nosotros.html:**

```
<section class="menu">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav" id="nav-menu">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="Nosotros.html">Nosotros</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicio al cliente</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>
```

Y así sucesivamente.

En cuanto al borde en el *item* seleccionado, podrías agregar en tu código CSS:

```
.nav-item {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.active {
  border-color: #606060;
}
```

Comment: se lo agregue funciono, pero no navega

Comment: Había asumido que querías navegar entre pestañas. Sin embargo, ¿podrías indicarme, aparte de agregar la clase `.active` qué deseas hacer? Es para ayudarlo.
Saludos

Comment: lo que quiero hacer es que el item seleccionado tenga un borde

Comment: Ya modifiqué la respuesta. Cualquier duda me avisas. Saludos

Comment: Oye y sabes como es cuando hay un solo menu? es que en wordpress es un solo menu para todo el sito

Comment: Envíame el enlace para evaluarlo.

Comment: ya lo logre era, agregar una función en el functions.php